# How can I use react-doc-viewer to render local files?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render a local file i have with react-doc-viewer but I cant get it to work

this is how i declare the file

```
const docs = [ { uri: "http://localhost:8080/124124_AN_1684893152034.xlsx", fileType: 'xlsx' }, // Local File ];
```

this i show i try to render it

```
<DocViewer pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers} documents={docs} style={{width: 500, height: 500}} config={{ header: { disableHeader: true,
```

any help on what i am missing will be appreciated.